# Unable to delete root-owned file under /tmp

Tags: root, rm, acl, tmp, xattr

The file and folder are owned by root but I did `sudo chmod ugo+rw` on both, which I confirmed with `ls -l`.
Still, I cannot remove the file as normal user.

```bash
❯ ls -ld /tmp /tmp/perm
drwxrwxrwt 46 root root 1160 Jan  9 17:41 /tmp
-rw-rw-rw-  1 root root    3 Jan  9 17:40 /tmp/perm
❯ rm /tmp/perm
rm: cannot remove '/tmp/perm': Operation not permitted
```

No attr and no ACL configured:

```bash
❯ lsattr -d /tmp
---------------------- /tmp
❯ getfacl /tmp
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: tmp
# owner: root
# group: root
# flags: --t
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx
```

Doing the same within subfolders works.

`/tmp` is part of an ext4 system mounted at `/` running under Arch Linux.

Comment: I doubt it will be relevant, but just in case, please [edit] your question and include the operating system you are using and the file system of `/tmp`.

Comment: done, thanks for the hint :)

Comment: /tmp of ext4 type ??? errr ??? Doesn't ArchLinux mount /tmp on a tmpfs per default ?

Comment: @MC68020 I remember Solaris mounting /tmp on tmpfs, but I don't recall seeing Debian-based Linux distros doing that.  I had to disable it on many Sun boxes back in the day.  Too often large files were dumped into /tmp and used up all the RAM...

Answer (score 3):

That's because the sticky bit `t` in `/tmp`: `drwxrwxrwt 46 root root 1160 Jan  9 17:41 /tmp`.

From `man chmod`:

> RESTRICTED DELETION FLAG OR STICKY BIT
>
> > The restricted deletion flag or sticky bit is a single bit, whose interpretation depends on the file type.  For directories, it prevents unprivileged users from removing or renaming a file in the directory unless they own the file or the directory; this is called the restricted deletion flag for the directory, and is commonly found on world-writable directories like /tmp.

You can set the sticky bit by using:

```bash
chmod +t /path/to/dir
```

or

```bash
chmod o+x,+t /path/to/dir
```

The difference between both is that the first one will set `T` instead of `t` if the directory has not execution permissions for *others*. Whereas `o+x,+t` will set both the execution permissions and the sticky bit.

In this case, **I do not recommend you** removing the sticky bit from `/tmp`. But if you want to remove it you should use:

```bash
sudo chmod -t /tmp
```

Or better, instead of removing the sticky bit just run `rm /tmp/perm` as root (or `sudo`).